# Matching both <space> and <tab> in a line with multiple coloumns in unix

Tags: grep, regular-expression

There are 200 plus files in a folder where some of the files consisting the following pattern in their records

`ABCD<Space><tab><Space>,EFGH,<SPACE>,`.

Without amending or replacing it, I just want to know the number of files with this format.

Comment: pattern to match is <spaces><tab><spaces>

Comment: I guessed `grep` does it, please provide some line of your files.

Comment: none of the below commands working for me, I tried with grep -l "$(echo '\ ' & '\t' & '\ ')," * which lists the files containing this pattern ( <space><tab><space>), but results produced all the files have tab or spaces. I am using bash and not any upgrade version to that

Answer (score 0):

Grep has Perl regexp mode (-P) and count-only (-c)

```
$ grep -c -P 'ABCD\ \t\ ,EFGH,\ ,' file
1
```

Comment: Almost. That counts the number of instances. The question asks for a count of the number of files containing such a pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the number of files which has the pattern

```
grep -rlP "ABCD \t ,EFGH, " directory   | wc -l
```

- `r` recursive file search
- `P` Perl mode
- `l` print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.The scanning will stop on the first match.
- line count

To get the list of files:

```
grep -rlP "ABCD \t ,EFGH, " directory   |  awk -F '/' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This command counts the number of files in the current directory that contain matches to your pattern:

```
grep -Psl 'ABCD \t ,EFGH, ,' * | wc -l
```

<sub>(In common with most other solutions it will miscount files that contain embedded newlines in their name. In a GNU world you can use `grep -PZsl '...pattern...' * | tr '\n\0' 'X\n' | wc -l` to fix that.)</sub>

Comment: Note that `-P` is also a GNU extension (though now supported by a few others). `--null` is slightly more portable than `-Z` IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`

```
(cd folder && grep -l $' \t ' ./*(D.)) | grep -c /
```

Will count the number of regular files in the `folder` directory  that contain at least one occurrence of `<space><tab><space>`.

Recursively:

```
(cd folder && grep -l $' \t ' .//**/*(D.)) | grep -c //
```

Recursively, you could also use `find`:

```
(cd folder && find .//. -type f -exec grep -l $' \t ' {} +) | grep -c //
```

If you only want to consider files where `<space><tab><space>` is found in the first column, change the pattern to `$'^[^,]* \t '`.

Comment: I've just realised what your `grep -l ... ./* | grep -c /` is doing. That's a neat pattern.